# Codeigniter Image Upload On Registration Form

Tags: php, image, codeigniter, upload

Hi guys I am new to Codeigniter and new to the MVC webdesign, and I've been trying to implement this image upload into my registration form with no success.

In another page where the user edits his profile i've added it successfully but for the life of me i can't add it to this register form. It's not uploading to my database or to my server

Here is what I've tried:

```
//upload controller
public function do_upload() {
     $user = $this->ion_auth->user()->row();
     $config['upload_path']   = './some/folder/'; 
     $config['allowed_types'] = 'jpg|png'; 
     $config['max_size']      = 2000; 
     $config['overwrite'] = TRUE;
     $current_user_id = $user->id;
     $current_user_username = $user->username;
     $config['file_name'] = $current_user_id . "_" . $current_user_username;
     //$config['max_width']     = 1024; 
     //$config['max_height']    = 768;  
     $this->load->library('upload', $config);

     if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload('userfile')) {
        $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
        redirect('/', 'refresh');   
     }
     else { 
            $vars['user'] = $user;
            $current_user = $user->id;      
            $vars['recent_messages'] = $this->ss_messages_model->find_all_array(array('id_user' => $user->id), 'date_added desc', 5);
            $image_data = $this->upload->data();
            $data = array('userfile' => $image_data['file_name']);
            $this->ion_auth->update($user->id, $data);

     }
  }

//register function in the auth controller 
function register()
    {
        $this->data['title'] = "Register User";
        $this->data['lang'] = $this->clang;
        **$this->do_upload();**
        $tables = $this->config->item('tables','ion_auth');

        //validate form input
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('first_name', $this->lang->line('register_fname'), 'alpha_space|required|xss_clean'); 
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('last_name', $this->lang->line('register_user_validation_lname_label'), 'alpha_space|required|xss_clean');

        if ($this->form_validation->run() == true)
        {
            $username = strtolower($this->input->post('first_name')) . ' ' . strtolower($this->input->post('last_name'));
            $email    = strtolower($this->input->post('email'));
            $password = $this->input->post('password');

            $additional_data = array(
            'first_name' => $this->input->post('first_name'),
            'last_name'  => $this->input->post('last_name'),
            **'userfile'      => $this->input->post('userfile');**
            );
        }
        if ($this->form_validation->run() == true && $this->ion_auth->register($username, $password, $email, $additional_data))
        {
            //check to see if we are creating the user
            //redirect them back to the admin page
            $this->session->set_flashdata('message', $this->ion_auth->messages());
            $this->_render_page("auth/_success");
        }
        else
        {
            //display the register user form
            //set the flash data error message if there is one
            $this->data['message'] = (validation_errors() ? validation_errors() : ($this->ion_auth->errors() ? $this->ion_auth->errors() : $this->session->flashdata('message')));

            $this->data['image']= $this->_create_captcha();

            $this->_render_page('auth/register', $this->data);
        }
    }

**//view**
<div class="input-box">
            <div class="agent-lable"><?php echo "Picture: (jpg or png)"; ?>
            </div><br>
            <input type = "file" name = "userfile" size = "20" />
    </div>
```

Comment: Without success? Why? Do you have any errors? Is your upload failing? Which part is not successful?

Comment: It's not uploading to my database or to my server when the user clicks on the register button.

Comment: You want to add the file to the newly registered user yet (1) you are attempting to add the file before the user is created (2) you are getting `$this->ion_auth->user()->row();` the current users row ... which if they aren't logged in (which they aren't as they havent registed yet) will be null

Answer (score 1):

You need to realize a few things:

1. At the start of the registration function where you call `do_upload` the user isn't created yet. As you want to add an image for the user, you need to wait until the IonAuth `register` function adds them to the database.
2. `$this->ion_auth->user()->row()` when the user id isn't specified gets the row of the current user: "If a user id is not passed the id of the currently logged in user will be used." As nobody is logged in yet `$user->username` will be null and `$user->id` in the update function will also be null - hence it is not updating; and if it did, it wouldn't be for the correct user!

You should modifiy your `register` function like so:

```
function register() {
        echo 'register function triggered <br>';
        $this->data['title'] = "Register User";
        $this->data['lang'] = $this->clang;
        //$this->do_upload(); User isn't created yet!!

        //$tables = $this->config->item('tables', 'ion_auth');

        //validate form input
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('first_name', $this->lang->line('register_fname'), 'alpha_space|required|xss_clean');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('last_name', $this->lang->line('register_user_validation_lname_label'), 'alpha_space|required|xss_clean');

        if ($this->form_validation->run()) {
            echo 'form validation passed <br>';
            $username = strtolower($this->input->post('first_name')) . ' ' . strtolower($this->input->post('last_name'));
            $email = strtolower($this->input->post('email'));
            $password = $this->input->post('password');
            $additional_data = array(
                'first_name' => $this->input->post('first_name'),
                'last_name' => $this->input->post('last_name'),
                    //'userfile' => $this->input->post('userfile') files are not in $_POST array
            );
            $register = $this->ion_auth->register($username, $password, $email, $additional_data);
            if ($register) {
                echo 'user successfully registered <br>';
                print_r($register);
                /**
                 * The user is already registered here... If the upload function fails, we should let
                 * them know somewhere else other than the register form as this hasn't affected
                 * their registration
                 */
                $upload = $this->do_upload($register);
                if ($upload !== true) {
                    $this->session->set_flashdata('message', $upload);
                }
                $this->session->set_flashdata('message', $this->ion_auth->messages());
                $this->_render_page("auth/_success");
            } else {
                $this->data['message'] = $this->ion_auth->errors();
                $this->data['image'] = $this->_create_captcha();
                $this->_render_page('auth/register', $this->data);
            }
        } else {
            $this->data['message'] = validation_errors();
            $this->data['image'] = $this->_create_captcha();
            $this->_render_page('auth/register', $this->data);
        }
    }
```

and your `do_upload` function to accept the newly created user id as a parameter:

```
public function do_upload($uid) {
    // added new users uid
    $user = $this->ion_auth->user($uid)->row();
    $config['upload_path'] = './some/folder/';
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'jpg|png';
    $config['max_size'] = 2000;
    $config['overwrite'] = TRUE;
    $current_user_id = $user->id;
    $current_user_username = $user->username;
    $config['file_name'] = $current_user_id . "_" . $current_user_username;
    //$config['max_width']     = 1024; 
    //$config['max_height']    = 768;  
    $this->load->library('upload', $config);

    if (!$this->upload->do_upload('userfile')) {
        echo '<br> upload errors <br>';
        exit($this->upload->display_errors());
        return $this->upload->display_errors();
        //$error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
        //redirect('/', 'refresh');
    } else {
        echo 'upload success <br>';
        // variables unused in scope
        //$vars['user'] = $user;
        //$current_user = $user->id;
        //$vars['recent_messages'] = $this->ss_messages_model->find_all_array(array('id_user' => $user->id), 'date_added desc', 5);
        $image_data = $this->upload->data();
        $data = array('userfile' => $image_data['file_name']);
        $this->ion_auth->update($user->id, $data);
        return true;
    }
}
```

It is important to note. Even if for some reason the upload function fails, we shouldn't re-show the register form... the user is already registered (remember, we needed their id). Instead redirect them to the success page and just say hey, we couldn't upload your profile picture.

If your profile picture is required I would suggest to validate that it exists before continuing with the register function, so like before form validation.

If you didn't want the username and user id to for the image name there is another option than this code that is cleaner.

Comment: I have tried your solution but with no success. The log isn't showing anything. I've called the "upload" library in the auth controller where the register function is located with $this->load->library('upload'), and did exactly as you said. Maybe the problem is $upload = $this->do_upload($register['id']); where I am not passing the 'userfile' from the input ?

Comment: no need to pass `userfile` the $_FILES array will be "viewable" for the duration of the post until a new post. can you try instead of `return $this->upload->display_errors();` => `exit($this->upload->display_errors());`

Comment: i've updated my code with some information markers. this will help us debug what is wrong. please update all the code and run the system again and let me know *exactly* what it is outputting.

Comment: Ooops my bad, hold up, you presumably have `email_activation` enabled in the config of Ion_Auth ... in such a case the `register` function of Ion Auth doesn't return an array but instead just the id (I took some of this code out of my system where i have email activation disabled to use my own system). So instead of doing `$register['id']` pass just `$register` which is the id of the new user. Try that instead. So the only line you have to change is `$this->do_upload($register);` ... If that still doesn't work refer to my previous comment.

Comment: Maybe it's because of my view, where I initialize the form like this: <?php $attributes = array('id' => 'form-login-pop'); echo form_open_multipart(site_url('auth/register'), $attributes);?> . In another page where the user is editing his data i initialize the form by using (form_open_multipart(upload/do_upload) and the upload is working.

Comment: The only difference is that in that edit page i close the edit form </form> then i initialize the upload with <?php echo form_open_multipart('upload/do_upload'); ?> then the <input type ="file"> etc then close the upload form </form> and continue with the edit form. How can i include in my view the upload form along with aut/register form ?

Comment: Unrelated but if you feel unsure post your relevant view code. Please refer to my comment 'ive updated the code' and run it to see where the break points are.

Comment: `//view form of my register file <?php $attributes = array('id' => 'form-login-pop'); echo form_open_multipart(site_url('auth/register'), $attributes);?> <div class="input-box">
   <div class="agent-lable"><?php echo "Document de identitate: (jpg sau png)"; ?>
   </div><br>
   <input type = "file" name = "userfile" size = "20" />
 </div>`

Comment: it's messing up my captcha validation. Showing "please insert correct captcha" everytime i submit the form with the correct captcha..maybe data['image'] is the fault

Comment: I see the "register function triggered" echoed in the form though

Comment: logically i didnt touch your captcha validation, maybe remove it for the tests if that is the only echo you see im not sure what you are doing but its obvious then why the upload isnt happening